# Loading more than one Spark parquet file into a Spark table using R sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm trying to load more than one parquet file into one Spark table using R `sparklyr`. The attached code shows how I am doing it.

```
spark_load_data <- function(db_conn, test_period)
{
    library(DBI)
    #
    overwrite <- TRUE
    #
    for (ts in seq(as.Date(test_period["START_DATE","VALUE"]),
                   as.Date(test_period["END_DATE","VALUE"]),
                   by="day")) {
        #
        # date to load
        #
        td <- format(as.Date(ts,origin="1970-01-01"), "%Y-%m-%d")
        #
        # load parquet files
        #
        tbl <- "pcidata"
        pq_path <- paste0("s3://<path>/PciData/transaction_date=", td)
        read_in <- spark_read_parquet(db_conn, 
                                      name=tbl,
                                      path=pq_path,
                                      overwrite=overwrite)
        #
        overwrite <- FALSE
    }
}
```

I would like to have the Spark table contains all the parquet files, instead it either overwrites the data or it just skips it. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

The `read.parquet` method actually supports providing multiple file paths, which means we can write a simple wrapper:

```
read_parquet_multiple <- function(sc, paths) {
  spark_session(sc) %>% invoke("read") %>% invoke("parquet", as.list(paths))
}
```

And then use this to read multiple files, for example (full example including connecting to a local spark instance and writing 2 parquet files to load from):

```
library(sparklyr); library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

# Write 1:10 into 2 separate parquet files
sdf_seq(sc, 1, 3, repartition = NULL) %>% spark_write_parquet("batch_1")
sdf_seq(sc, 4, 6, repartition = NULL) %>% spark_write_parquet("batch_2")

# Read mulitple files
dataset <- sc %>% read_parquet_multiple(paths = c("batch_1", "batch_2"))

# Collect to show the results
dataset %>% collect()

# # A tibble: 6 x 1
# id
# <int>
#   1     2
#   2     3
#   3     5
#   4     6
#   5     1
#   6     4
```